# H2: Slow query execution when using IN (..) operator, even though UNION with individual = conditions works fine

Tags: database, performance, indexing, h2

I am struggling with slow query execution for a WHERE-clause such as `field IN ('value1', 'value2' )`, whereas equivalent queries (using UNION or CTE, see below) are performed as expected. Self-contained SQL below, tested with the standalone console (`java -jar h2-2.1.214.jar`).

```
DROP TABLE test IF EXISTS;
CREATE TABLE test(
  name CHARACTER VARYING,
  type CHARACTER VARYING,
 PRIMARY KEY (type, name)
);

INSERT INTO test 
SELECT 
  'NAME' || name_range.x, 
  'TYPE' || type_range.x
        FROM system_range(0,99999) name_range
  CROSS JOIN system_range(0,9) type_range;

-- 1 million rows
SELECT count(*) FROM test;

-- this is OK: "scanCount: 2"
EXPLAIN ANALYZE 
  SELECT * FROM test WHERE name = 'NAME9999' AND type = 'TYPE1';

-- following two are NOT OK: "scanCount: 200001, reads: 8137"
-- looks like the PK can only be used for field "name"
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
   SELECT * FROM test WHERE name = 'NAME9999' AND type IN ( 'TYPE1', 'TYPE2' );

EXPLAIN ANALYZE
   SELECT * FROM test WHERE name = 'NAME9999' AND ( type = 'TYPE1' OR type = 'TYPE2' );

-- next two are OK again: "scanCount: 2"
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
   SELECT * FROM test WHERE name = 'NAME9999' AND type = 'TYPE1' 
  UNION
   SELECT * FROM test WHERE name = 'NAME9999' AND type = 'TYPE2';

EXPLAIN ANALYZE
  WITH types AS (SELECT * FROM ( VALUES ('TYPE1'), ('TYPE2') ) AS t(type) )
  SELECT * FROM test 
    JOIN types t ON test.type = t.type
   WHERE name = 'NAME9999'
```

As the `IN ( ... )`-condition isn't really complex, I would assume that the primary key can be used. Am I missing something? Adding more indices (`CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_type ON test(type);`) doesn't change the situation.

NOTE: when changing the primary key definition to `PRIMARY KEY (name, type)`, the problem kind of disappears for this particular example - however this still wouldn't entirely fix the general problem as I don't have full control over the schema definition and even if I had, similar queries where other fields from the PK are appearing in `field IN ( ... )` would still be slow.

Comment: "...I would assume that the primary key can be used..." -- not really. That would require the operator "Index Skip Scan" implemented in other high end database engines (and also in MySQL), that is not implemented in H2.

Comment: According to the execution plans I got from your queries, H2 uses the index (related to the PK) only when it's straightforward to do so. For anything else, it goes with a table scan. That's why the `UNION` is performant and the last query as as well.

Comment: Now tracked in [github](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/3747)

Comment: I don't think this is a bug. Different database engines implement different operators. You cannot expect this tiny database to implement high end features available in Oracle, PostgreSQL, or DB2.

Comment: Sure, but that's not what I said. A github issue is just that: an issue. I leave it to the h2 maintainers if they want to interpret this as a bug, a feature request, something in between or entirely different. On top of that: we're talking about `IN (list of literals)`, not `IN (SELECT ..)`. Nothing really high-end from my POV, but of course I'm also not a DB engine developer myself. Anyhow, I found a workaround that works for me (mentioned in the linked github issue).

Comment: Looks like this will become more visible with hibernate 6? https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/upgrade-to-hibernate-6-insert-performance-with-embedded-ids/7515?u=sibsssidor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really a conclusive answer, more a workaround: for my particular use-case, it's acceptable to entirely drop the primary key after populating this table, and instead add single-field indices for further lookups. This way, above `SELECT`-queries don't require excessive scans even without hints like USE INDEX.